# Return Value Optimization And Initializaton of Heap Allocated Variables

Tags: c++, rvo

When initializing a stack allocated variable from a temporary RVO occurs, but it doesn't when initializing a heap allocated variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

    A(const A &other)
    {
        cout << "Copy A!" << endl;
    }

    A(A &&other)
    {
        cout << "Move A!" << endl;
    }
};

A foo()
{
    return A();
}

int main()
{
    A a1 = foo(); //Constructs A only!
    A *a2 = new A(foo()); //Constructs A and moves it
}
```

Output:
Move A!

It seems to me that the compiler is creating A in the stack, getting the pointer to heap allocated memory and then moving A, but why doesn't it just gets the pointer first and **then** passes it to foo, so A can be constructed directly in the heap allocated chunk?

EDIT:
Compiled with g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0, using `-O3 -std=c++17`

EDIT 2:
Updated to MinGW 7.4.0 and now it optimizes out both the copy and the move.

Comment: If you compile in C++17 mode, you should see no copies and no moves in both cases.

Comment: Output with what? Compiler? Version? Platform?

Comment: Are you sure it's MinGW-W64 v5.3.0? That version doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They probably mean mingw-w64 build of gcc 5.3.0. Which is from 2015, which would explain incomplete C++17 support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can, with a little extra effort, and [the rules of C++17 actually *require* your compiler to go to this effort](http://www.cplusplus2017.info/c17-guaranted-copy-elision/).

So put on C++17 mode and enjoy!

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52e731e527dba36f))

If you don't want to use C++17 for whatever reason, as long as you use a compiler that supports it then it will likely apply this optimisation in earlier standard modes anyway (since they already had to write the code to do it). For example, Coliru's GCC does so in C++14 mode even at `-O0`. In other words, perhaps you simply need to upgrade your compiler.

If your compiler *doesn't* do this in C++17 mode, it is non-compliant to the standard.

That could be a bug, like [this old GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71913); MinGW-w64 v5.0.3 [should approximate to GCC 7.2.0](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download), in which I understand the bug to be fixed, but as MinGW is not a direct clone of the GCC codebase it could be lagging behind slightly in this regard. You could try upgrading to MinGW-x64 v6.

I've also found Visual Studio 2017 to have unreliable copy elision.

Comment: Yep, it seems my compiler doesn't comply to the standard, yet it is a very widespread compiler, really weird, for the first time I'm considering changing compiler.

Comment: MinGW _does_ have its limitations; this would not be the first. Your version is equivalent to GCC 7, though, which is kinda old. It's worth noting that I've found Visual Studio's guaranteed-elision support to be somewhat lacking as well.

Comment: (though this version of GCC [does purport to support guaranteed elision](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17))

Comment: @HenriqueInonhe I think I found the bug reference

Comment: To be honest I didn't install this compiler myself, it came with Qt, I'll see if I can update it without breaking anything

Comment: Please tell us this sort of detail up-front next time. You never know whether it's relevant!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit mingw-w64 uses the gcc source files unmodified to build the compiler; with some additional source files for things such as the C library (since glibc is not supported on windows)

Comment: The [source download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/) only includes the library support and winapi headers ; you clone the gcc source separately if you want to do your own build